# How does my application discover the address/port of the *local* envoy sidecar proxy on AWS App Mesh (ECS/Fargate with dynamic ports)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, envoyproxy, aws-app-mesh

If I'm running on AWS App Mesh / ECS (not Kubernetes) - where does my application get the address/port of the local (it's own) Envoy sidecar in order to communicate with other services on the mesh?

Given this is ECS (Fargate) and I'm running with dynamic ports, it's not as though I can call e.g. localhost:some_known_port_here.

So, when my app goes:

my app (1) -> local envoy sidecar (2) -> remote envoy sidecar (3) -> remote app (4)

How do I make the hop from 1 to 2?  Not sure where that address comes from.

Comment: From what I can tell, App Mesh (Envoy proxy) relies on iptables manipulation (see the "more" bit that needs expanding here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/appmesh-getting-started.html#update-services) in order to intercept traffic into and out of the app.  

That whole process requires static ports rather than dynamic (as is currently supported by ALBs).  Moving to static ports would cause port collisions and hence ECS to schedule/place onto separate EC2 instances in turn increasing EC2 costs.

Comment: Annnnnnd, now I'm guessing that the port collisions don't happen due to the magic of awsvpc networking mode.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be through App Mesh now. Application ports are specified in the configuration so that the routing table is setup to *not* forward the traffic on those ports back to the Envoy but to the App.

How are you using dynamic ports today? Why wouldn't awsvpc mode wouldn't fit your need here?

With ECS task networking mode multiple containers(tasks) can run on the same port in a given ECS instance. There should not be any collision.

If you need support for dynamic ports, you can open a feature request here: https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-roadmap/issues